# convert dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in .csv file in c#

Tags: c#, csv, date, datetime

I have a CSV file like this:

```
abc;30.11.2021;xyz
```

I need to convert the date value to this format:

```
abc;2021-11-30;xyz
```

any ideas for that?

Currenty I do this:

```
//config Ini auslesen für Quell- und Zieldatei
        var dic = File.ReadAllLines("config.ini")
          .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
          .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
        //Wert für Quelle
        string source = dic["source"];
        //Wert für das Ziel
        string target = dic["target"];

        string filePath = source ;

        var csv = File
        .ReadLines(source)
        .Select((line, index) => index == 0
           ? line + ";ExtID"                                     // Neue Kopfzeile
           : line + ";" + string.Concat(line.Split(';').Take(2)) // Spalte 1 + 2 in neue Spalte einfügen
         )
        .ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines(target, csv);
```

So I read an csv file, add a column and fill this column but to be honnest I don't know how to convert the date value.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Please show your current attempt at solving this, and indicate where exactly you're having problems.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work like that. No one will spoonfeed you an answer. Work for it and try to find a solution yourself. When you do, you will have specific doubts, those you can bring here. This platform is not a free coding service.

Comment: Parse the string to a date (giving the current format) and convert it to a string using `ToString` (giving the new format). The rest is CSV manipulation.

Comment: Basically 2 options: 1) creation the transformation function that will receive the string and produce the new string (`.split('.')` etc) 2) go through a DateTime parsing then a text conversion.

Comment: 3rd way. Use CSV define the class representing the data. [Read](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/) value and write them back using the new format. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/697. Thats 1 class definition for the object 2 for writer and and readder mapper and 3 lines of codes using one streamreader and a writer.

Answer (score 0):

use `ParseExact` to convert the string to `DateTime` and use `ToString` to convert back to the desired format

```
var s = DateTime.ParseExact("30.11.2021", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("newfile.csv"))
 {
     foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("oldfile.csv"))
     {
         string[] items = line.Split(new[] { ';' });

         string newDateFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(items[1], "dd.MM.yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

         writer.Write(items[0]);
         writer.Write(';');
         writer.Write(newDateFormat);
         writer.Write(';');
         writer.Write(items[2]);
         writer.Write(';');
         writer.WriteLine();
     }
 }
```

Replace "oldfile.csv" with the input file and the output will be saved to "newfile.csv".